# How to make a function in python that takes a product and re substitutes in equation to get a solution

Tags: python, function, equation

I'm trying to make a function in Python 3 that takes an initial value, plugs it into an equation, takes that solution, and iterates the process as many times as specified as a parameter of a function. The end goal is to have a value that when plugged into the equation returns the same value.

The equation I was thinking of using is:

```
def f(x):
    return tanh(5*x)
```

Thanks

Comment: "The end goal is to have a value that when plugged into the equation returns the same value." What does that even mean? Just return the parameter value?

Comment: Just to be clear, would you want to iterate a process a given number of times or get a value when plugged into the equation returns the same value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with a for loop:

```
from math import tanh

# the function you defined
def f(x):
    return tanh(5*x)

# create a separate function that repeats the process
def iterate(initial, iterations):
    for _ in range(iterations):
        initial = f(initial)
    return initial

print(iterate(10, 10000))
```

Note that not all functions will reach a point where `f(x) -> x` but in this case it does

Comment: Thank you so much for the help, this was actually much simpler than I originally thought!